# Linear Algebra - backward substitution

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it faster to do back substitution that multiplying A by a vector?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing and how comfortable you are with each process.  Try practicing both and seeing which you feel better about.

Answer (score 1):

The back-substitution step in Gaussian elimination plus back-substitution takes 
$\frac{1}{2}N^2 + O(N)$ multiply/add type steps.  Multiplying a vector by an $N\times N$ matrix takes $N^2 + O(N)$.  Back-substitution is faster, in that sense.